# Have multiple style changes based on scroll position on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add multiple style change points based on if I scroll past a certain DIV, I've tried modifying the single style change script that I have but all attempts have gone unsuccessful.

The script -

```
var targetOffset = $("#contentstart").offset().top - 100;

var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {   
        $('.mainnav').css({"background":"#016FBA"});
        $('.mainnav').css({"height":"50px"});
        $('button.navtoggle').css({"margin":"5px auto"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a').css({"color":"#ffffff"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a:hover').css({"color":"#000000"})
    } else {
      $('.mainnav').css({"background":""});
      $('ul.mainlinks a').css({"color":""});
        $('ul.mainlinks a:hover').css({"color":""});
        $('.mainnav').css({"height":""});
        $('button.navtoggle').css({"margin":""});
    }
});
```

Ideally I'd like to add 3 more style change points.

Could someone give me a hand with this?

Thanks In Advance

EDIT (more info) 
I want the navigation bar to change colour as I scroll through different areas of my parallax website. For example, it starts off being semi-transparent, then once I get to the about section it changes to grey and orange, then this is where the problem is. I want it to also change colour at my skills section, blog section then finally at the contact section. And what I tried was a duplicate of that script but with a different target div.

Comment: what exactly is your problem?
Don't you know how to concat multiple conditions?

Please describe what you have tried, and what you mean by "gone unsuccessful".
What did you expect? What did you get?

Comment: Sorry let me explain a little better.
I want the navigation bar to change colour as I scroll through different areas of my parallax website. For example, it starts off being semi-transparent, then once I get to the about section it changes to grey and orange, then this is where the problem is.
I want it to also change colour at my skills section, blog section then finally at the contact section.

And what I tried was a duplicate of that script but with a different target div.

So in answer to your question, no, I don't know how to write multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

> So in answer to your question, no, I don't know how to write multiple conditions.

Well, that's a thing we can fix.
That's the Syntax for multiple conditions.

```
if(condition1){
    //gets executed if condition1 is true
}else if(condition2){
    //if condition1 is false but condition2 is true
}else if(condition3){
    //if condition1 and 2 are false but condition3 is true
}else{
    //if none of these conditions are true
}
```

You always need one if-block
you can have as many else if-blocks as you want
and at the end you can have an optional else-block

And you nest conditions.

Comment: Using that format i wrote this, however, it doesn't work. Any ideas why?
- Check answer below

Answer (score 0):

In answer to Thomas -

```
var targetOffset = $("#contentstart").offset().top - 100;
var targetOffset2 = $("#skillset").offset().top;
var targetOffset3 = $("#mywork").offset().top;

var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {   
        $('.mainnav').css({"background":"#767676"});
        $('.mainnav').css({"height":"50px"});
        $('button.navtoggle').css({"margin":"5px auto"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a').css({"color":"#FFC330"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a:hover').css({"color":"#000000"})
    } 
    else if($w.scrollTop() > targetOffset2){
        $('.mainnav').css({"background":"#fff"});
        $('.mainnav').css({"height":"50px"});
        $('button.navtoggle').css({"margin":"5px auto"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a').css({"color":"#000"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a:hover').css({"color":"#000000"})
    }
    else if($w.scrollTop() > targetOffset3){
        $('.mainnav').css({"background":"#666"});
        $('.mainnav').css({"height":"50px"});
        $('button.navtoggle').css({"margin":"5px auto"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a').css({"color":"#000"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a:hover').css({"color":"#000000"})
    }else {
      $('.mainnav').css({"background":""});
      $('ul.mainlinks a').css({"color":""});
        $('ul.mainlinks a:hover').css({"color":""});
        $('.mainnav').css({"height":""});
        $('button.navtoggle').css({"margin":""});
    }
});
```

Using that format this is what I wrote, however, only the first if statement is read.

Comment: let me guess, the offsets are increaing. Tell me: `offset > 150` is true  is `offset > 100` then also true? Does the first condition also include the other ones? Maybe you want to put the conditions in an order where they exclude each other, like descending, or maybe you want to restrain the conditions to a range, by also giving them an upper limit?

Comment: The only limit I can add is the bottom of the div, as there's too much content to give a fixed height, whilst also maintaining responsive.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `elseif` not `else if`

Try;

```
var targetOffset = $("#contentstart").offset().top - 100;
var targetOffset2 = $("#skillset").offset().top;
var targetOffset3 = $("#mywork").offset().top;

var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {   
        $('.mainnav').css({"background":"#767676"});
        $('.mainnav').css({"height":"50px"});
        $('button.navtoggle').css({"margin":"5px auto"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a').css({"color":"#FFC330"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a:hover').css({"color":"#000000"})
    } 
    elseif($w.scrollTop() > targetOffset2){
        $('.mainnav').css({"background":"#fff"});
        $('.mainnav').css({"height":"50px"});
        $('button.navtoggle').css({"margin":"5px auto"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a').css({"color":"#000"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a:hover').css({"color":"#000000"})
    }
    elseif($w.scrollTop() > targetOffset3){
        $('.mainnav').css({"background":"#666"});
        $('.mainnav').css({"height":"50px"});
        $('button.navtoggle').css({"margin":"5px auto"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a').css({"color":"#000"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a:hover').css({"color":"#000000"})
    }else {
      $('.mainnav').css({"background":""});
      $('ul.mainlinks a').css({"color":""});
        $('ul.mainlinks a:hover').css({"color":""});
        $('.mainnav').css({"height":""});
        $('button.navtoggle').css({"margin":""});
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

you may try this then, another approach.

```
var targetOffset = $("#contentstart").offset().top - 100;
var targetOffset2 = $("#skillset").offset().top;
var targetOffset3 = $("#mywork").offset().top;

var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){

    if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {   
        $('.mainnav').css({"background":"#767676"});
        $('.mainnav').css({"height":"50px"});
        $('button.navtoggle').css({"margin":"5px auto"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a').css({"color":"#FFC330"});
        $('ul.mainlinks a:hover').css({"color":"#000000"})
    }else{ 
        if($w.scrollTop() > targetOffset2){
            $('.mainnav').css({"background":"#fff"});
            $('.mainnav').css({"height":"50px"});
            $('button.navtoggle').css({"margin":"5px auto"});
            $('ul.mainlinks a').css({"color":"#000"});
            $('ul.mainlinks a:hover').css({"color":"#000000"})
        }else{
            if($w.scrollTop() > targetOffset3){
                $('.mainnav').css({"background":"#666"});
                $('.mainnav').css({"height":"50px"});
                $('button.navtoggle').css({"margin":"5px auto"});
                $('ul.mainlinks a').css({"color":"#000"});
                $('ul.mainlinks a:hover').css({"color":"#000000"})
            }else{
                $('.mainnav').css({"background":""});
                $('ul.mainlinks a').css({"color":""});
                $('ul.mainlinks a:hover').css({"color":""});
                $('.mainnav').css({"height":""});
                $('button.navtoggle').css({"margin":""});
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That stopped it from working altogether, I believe you are thinking of PHP for elseif.
Thanks anyway

Comment: Only the first if statement and the single else statement is working again